# Dockerの同じコンテナにPythonとRを導入する方法について教えてください。

Tags: docker

はじめまして。
Dockerの初学者なのですが、掲題について教えて頂ければと思います。

Amazon Linux2で構築したサーバにPythonとRを導入したコンテナを1つ構築したいです。
そういったコンテナを構築する場合はDockerFileの作成などが必要なのでしょうか

--
PythonのみやRのみ導入されたコンテナを作成することはできます。

どうすればPythonやRなどの複数のソフトウェアや言語を導入した１つのコンテナを作成することができるのでしょうか。

本当に調べ方すらわからずに困っています。
なにか検索のフックになるような、、一言でも構いませんのでどなたかご教示いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 例えば Ruby のみのコンテナを起動することはできますか？ / あなたの理解度は第三者からはわからないので、単に「初学者です」や「実現したいこと」を説明するより、「自分でできたこと、反対に躓いた箇所」を詳しく説明した方がアドバイスも付きやすいです。

Comment: 参考: [Creating Docker with Ruby and R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69173373/2322778)